# Why is nginx showing "File not found" message when accessing 'index.php' files?

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I've come across a number of similar questions online but none of the solutions have worked. Admittedly my understanding of the inner workings is limited but I do know that my current nginx configuration has worked for months and up to just last night.

```
server {
    index index.html index.php;
    server_name XXX.xxx;
    root /var/www/ZZZ/;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~\.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }
    
    ...

}
```

fastcgi-php.conf contains the following:

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Comment: In the included file `fastcgi.conf`, do you set a value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME`?